# Psum not accumulating (Polymorphic Higher order function) without forcing a type

Tags: ocaml

New to OCaml and Functional Programming as a whole so I was having some problems with keeping the type ambiguous. I'm trying to make a function which takes in a symbol accum(which looks like (+) or (-.) or (*) etc.) and a function f. My current implementation is below and if let's say I passed in (** f (x) = 3x^2 + 5x + 6 **) but I always get '6' instead of '276' because in the else part I'm not summing adding the results of the previous rounds so I just get the final value of '6'.

I get type errors because of the + so when I throw floats in it breaks. How can I overcome this (let partial accept floats or ints but actually accumulate the answer)?

```
let rec powerSum(sign )(f):'a = 
  fun x ->
  if x = 0 then 
    f (x)
  else if x < 0 then 
    raise(Failure "Error arg isn't '+'")
  else
    powerSum sign f (x-1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you should use `accum` at some point.